# How to remove the timestamp from the output of timeParse function in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this parser:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");
```

This works fine but, it always appends the time and timezone to the date, although in the format above, I indicate to include only day, month, and year information.

Here is an example:

```
console.log(parseTime(new Date())); //Fri Jul 12 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Any ideas about how to exclude the timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

use timeFormat function and pass the function parseTime

```js
var parseTime = d3.timeFormat("%B %d, %Y");
console.log(parseTime(new Date));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had it, but put it wrong in the post.  Also, for some reason `timeFormat` is not working for me. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

```
(new Date()).toDateString()

d3.timeParse()().toDateString()
```

Without the zone the date will be ambiguous.